# word segmentation for hashtag using R

Tags: r, hashtag

i would like to do a word segmentation for hashtag. i want to split word in hashtag. this is my attempt but obviously it didn't work.

what i am trying to do

1. INPUT: #sometrendingtopic
2. OUTPUT: some trending topic

my attempt:

```
s<- "#sometrendingtopic"
tokenize_character_shingles(s)
tokenize_words(s)
tokenize_characters(s)
```

I got some information but it for python https://stackoverflow.com/.../r-split-string-by-symbol
thanks for future idea and guidance

Comment: `gsub('#','','#sometrendingtopic')` would remove hashtag from "#sometrendingtopic" then you can go on with hashtagless character object.

Comment: @SametSökel thanks, i will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... This is an absolutely non trivial task and I think can not be solved generally. Since you are missing a delimiter between your words, you basically need to extract substrings and check them against a dictionary of your desired language.
A very crude method, that will only extract the longest matches from left to right it can find is using `hunspell` which is designed for spell checking but can be "misused" to maybe solve this task:

```
split_words <- function(cat.string){
  split <- NULL
  start.char <- 1
  while(start.char < nchar(cat.string))
  {
    result <- NULL
    for(cur.char in start.char:nchar(cat.string))
    {
      test.string <- substr(cat.string,start.char,cur.char)
      test <- hunspell::hunspell(test.string)[[1]]
      if(length(test) == 0) result <- test.string
    }
    if(is.null(result)) return("")
    split <- c(split,result)
    start.char <- start.char + nchar(result)
  }
  split
}


input <- c("#sometrendingtopic","#anothertrendingtopic","#someveryboringtopic")

# Clean the hashtag from the input
input <- sub("#","",input)
#apply word split
result <- lapply(input,split_words)
result
[[1]]
[1] "some"     "trending" "topic"   

[[2]]
[1] "another"  "trending" "topic"   

[[3]]
[1] "some"   "very"   "boring" "topic"
```

Please keep in mind that this method is far from perfect in multiple ways:

1. It is relatively slow.
2. It will greedily match from left to right. So if we for example have the hashtag
   `input <- "#averyboringtopic"` the result will be

```
[[3]]
[1] "aver"   "y"      "boring" "topic"
```

Since "aver" apparently is a possible word in this specific dictionary.
So: Use at your own risk and improve upon this!